# syslog-ng install finished without the needed files

Tags: syslog, syslog-ng

I downloaded syslog-ng OSE from the site (version 3.4.0alpha3)
successfully run

```
./configure
make
make install
```

but I've got no /etc/syslog-ng.conf
nor /etc/init.d/syslog-ng

What might be the  reason?

env is centos 6.3

Answer (score 0):

This installs syslog-ng under `/usr/local` with your config as `/usr/local/etc/syslog-ng.conf` Please check`./configure --help` for options.

As far as I recall, there are init script examples in the source tree, but not automatically installed.